# How to get an explicit formula to count the multiples of $7$ between $a$ and $b$(not inclusive), in terms of $a, b, \overline{a}$ and $\overline{b}$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$\bar{a}$ and $\bar{b}$ are the residues of a and b mod 7. 
So,the attempt I made is to write: $$L=\frac{(b+ (7-\bar{b}))-(a+(7-\bar{a}))}{7}=\frac{(b-a)-(\bar{b}-\bar{a})}{7}$$

And this works, partially, since $\bar{b}$ and $\bar{a}$ must be taken as the positive canonical representatives for each one. I had committed the mistake of putting $\bar{b}-\bar{a}=\displaystyle\overline{b-a}$, so that L would just be the quotient between $b-a$ and 7, ignoring the remainder. But this doesn't work since here  $\bar{b}$ and $\bar{a}$ are taken as fixed numbers in Z. So in fact it could happen that $\displaystyle\overline{b-a}$ is the negative of $\bar{b}-\bar{a}$ (Take a=432 and b=519 and the formula won't work). Is there any better way?

Comment: I think this is the best formula we can get

Comment: $\lfloor {b\over 7}\rfloor-\lceil {a\over 7}\rceil$ didn't work ?